# Mirror Apple Watch UI to improve usability for left/right handed users

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

**Question**

Since Apple seems to be forcing storyboards on us to develop watch apps, how can I mirror the UI for a `WKInterfaceController` to support a left-handed and right-handed interface without having to maintain 2 separate "Scenes" in my storyboard?  Right now, I've copied and pasted the "left handed" scene and modified the UI so the controls are "mirrored" appropriately for use by righties.  However, anytime I want to update any part of that UI, I have to do it twice, which is very error prone.

**Background**

I'm in the final stages of developing an Apple Watch app to complement an existing iOS app.  One very important aspect of the watch app is that, while entering data on the watch, the hand interacting with the watch must not cover the screen.  My idea to meet this requirement is to align all of the controls you can tap along the same vertical edge of the watch.

There are 2 main controls.  Right now, they are stacked vertically and aligned on the left edge of the screen.  Therefore, left handed people (like me) who wear their watch on their right hand do not cover the screen at all when tapping the controls on the left edge of the watch worn on their right wrist.

However, with this same UI, right handed people who wear the watch on their left hand will be completely covering the screen when using these controls, and won't see the results of their input until they move their hand.

Therefore, I would like to provide "mirrored" UIs that are configurable depending which hand you wear your watch on.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure you understood my motivations.  I have 2 buttons aligned vertically to the left edge of the watch.  If you wear the watch on your right hand and tap with your left hand, your view of the screen is not blocked.  However, if the interface remains the same but wear your watch on the left hand, when you reach across the watch face with your right hand, you are blocking the screen while entering data.  This makes entry more error prone, and decreases usability.  I'm looking for a way to provide a mirrored interface to equalize the user experience regardless of handedness.

Comment: Ok, I am still not seeing it.  My natural action is to reach up from the bottom of the watch, so my hand doesn't block the screen on either wrist. Regardless you may have to stick with the two layouts as I don't believe there is any method to change the horizontal alignment of a WKInterfaceObject at runtime

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the screen you are trying to mirror?

Comment: @Paulw11 unless you always keep your index finger exactly perpendicular to your opposite arm, the rest of your hand attached to your index finger will block all or part of the screen while you're interacting with it.